# Set path to dll to build qt files

Tags: c++, qt, dll, build, dependencies

Running some Qt applications from Qt Creator, I found out that I need dependent dll's.

In order to execute the code from inside Qt Creator, I can see a few options.

1) place all dependent dll's in the same folder as the executable

Disadvantage: i may have to copy them each time those dll's are updated, or when i clean

2) I found that I can modify the Build Environment variable.

a) Add the dll folders to the path

seems like he best option, where is this setting saved ?

b) add some other env var  called LD_LIBRARY_PATH (found info about it here http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/6789 but then several forum questions mention it is bad...)

Both ideas sound good but the executable did not work (could not find the dlls)

3) someone suggested I could use DEPENDPATH in the project file... But logically this would only add  a path to find the lib files not the dll files ?

If this third option works, it would be best because I would not be constrained to settings inside Qt Creator, and would allow me to change multiple files with ease

What is the best option ?

Answer (score 0):

As for me, the very first variant is the most simple and minimally annoying. You can avoid to clean executables by determining different folders to temporary build objects and for builded binary files (so that every clean will delete just intermediate files). What about updating - tricky question, changing dependent dll is some kind of dangerous (who knows, what exactly changed with new update), that's why i can advice you not to do it so often.

Comment: some of the dependent dll's are created by other projects

Comment: then you can set output directory for this project matches the output directory of the above-mentioned project. Every single build of dependent libs will update them "in place", and thanks to automatically moving you can run app from QT Creator.